# CMD/Powershell: Commands not working with cURL. Cygwin works

Tags: windows, powershell, curl, cmd, cygwin

I'm trying to get this tutorial to work in CMD and Windows Powershell (Windows 7 64): http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/elasticsearch-in-5-minutes.html

The first command already doesn't work in CMD:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/blog/user/dilbert' -d '{ "name" : "Dilbert Brown" }'
```

I get the following error message:

```
curl: (1) Protocol 'http not supported or disabled in libcurl
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: name
curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Dilbert Brown
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
```

In Windows Powershell I get:

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token 'Dilbert': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@132b73b; line: 1, column: 33]]; ","status":400}curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 7
```

The same command works without any problems in Cygwin. How would I have to write the command to make it work in CMD and Windows Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell, the command is being called correctly, from a parsing perspective.

In cmd.exe, the single quotes are not valid. You will need to use double quotes to surround values.

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/blog/user/dilbert" -d "{ \"name\" : \"Dilbert Brown\" }"
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the Chrome addon "Sense" now. It makes working with ElasticSearch a lot easier than using cURL in a command line.